# Eclipse Content Assist function arguments auto-insert

Tags: r, eclipse, statet

I use [Eclipse StatET](http://www.walware.de/goto/statet) for R programming.
I am looking for a way to autocomplete function definition and insert parameters names.

Say I have following function (in R):

```
GetFC = function(key_, portf_name_, type_, db_name_){}
```

Then when I invoke content assist I see following picture:
[image: content assist invoked]

**Is there anyway, that content assist will insert not only the function name, but also all parameters?**

Like that:

[image: expected result]

Answer (score 1):

Use content assist twice: first time to choose your function, second time to see the arguments and select one:

[image: content assist to see arguments]

Comment: Tobias, indeed, this is the nice feature and I am aware of it. It is not exactly what I am looking for. I expect all parameters have been written, instead of clicking on them one after another to have them substituted. Moreover the current content assist doesn't keep the original order of parameters, but using alphabetical ordering instead :(